# What's the difference between various image resizing algorithms in the module of PIL.Image?

Tags: python, image, resize, python-imaging-library

As described in [Image.resize](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/reference/Image.html), there are multiple mothods to resize an image. For eexample, `PIL.Image.NEAREST`, `PIL.Image.BILINEAR`, `PIL.Image.BICUBIC` et al. But in [util.py](https://github.com/itijyou/ademxapp/blob/master/util/util.py) for semantic segmentation, `Image.ANTIALIAS` is used when target image  size is smaller than source image, and `Image.BICUBIC` is used when target image is larger, even `Image.LINEAR` is also used. What's the difference among them?

Answer (score 11):

These are described in detail in the docs under [Concepts](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/concepts.html#filters) (and also in the [release notes for the version where some were added](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releasenotes/3.4.0.html#new-resizing-filters). For example:

> `NEAREST`
>
> Pick one nearest pixel from the input image. Ignore all other input pixels.
>
> `BILINEAR`
>
> For resize calculate the output pixel value using linear interpolation on all pixels that may contribute to the output value. For other transformations linear interpolation over a 2x2 environment in the input image is used.
>
> `BICUBIC`
>
> For resize calculate the output pixel value using cubic interpolation on all pixels that may contribute to the output value. For other transformations cubic interpolation over a 4x4 environment in the input image is used.

And this chart:

[image: Filters comparison table: NEAREST fastest, LANZCOS best quality]

See [also](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releasenotes/2.7.0.html?highlight=antialias#antialias-renamed-to-lanczos):

> Antialias renamed to Lanczos

Comment: ,thank you very much! I know it will make little difference if I resize a RGB image. I have a matrix filled with number of datatype np.uint8, and I want to upscale this matrix to 1.5x. Supposing that there are two adjacent points with value of 0 and 10, what's value will be filled if I use these methods above?

Comment: I've no idea, to find the value the best thing to do is test it out and find out! Generally, go for LANZCOS, unless you're processing a large number of images and the performance is too slow.